# Do I need a visa to enter Tbilisi Georgia when I already have a UK tourist visa for 6 months

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, georgia-country, nigerian-citizens

I am a Nigerian and I have a UK tourist visa for 6 months. It was issued to me on 8/3/2017 and expires 8/9/2017. I would like to visit Tbilisi. Do I need a visa to enter Georgia?

Answer (score 5):

2023 Update: According to the [IATA Travel Centre](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/), a UK visa does still grant you visa-free access to Georgia (emphasis mine).

> Visa Exemptions:
> Passengers with a visa issued by an EEA Member State , Bahrain, Bermuda, Canada, Cayman Isl., Falkland Isl. (Malvinas), Gibraltar, Israel, Japan, Korea (Rep.), Kuwait, New Zealand, Oman, Qatar, Saudi Arabia, Switzerland, Turks and Caicos Isl., USA, United Arab Emirates or Virgin Isl. (British) for a maximum stay of 90 days. This does not apply to passengers with an e-visa.
> The maximum stay is granted within 180 days.
> **Passengers with a visa issued by Australia or United Kingdom for a maximum stay of 90 days.**
> The maximum stay is granted within 180 days.
> Passengers with a visa issued by Australia or United Kingdom for a maximum stay of 90 days.
> The maximum stay is granted within 180 days.
> Passengers with Georgian origins for a maximum stay of 30 days.

While the older answer is still correct in a way, since you can use a UK visa to enter Georgia, the wording is now incorrect as the UK is no longer an EEA member state.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=ni&DE=ge&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Passengers with a **valid visa** issued
>   by an **EEA Member State**, Australia, Bahrain,
>   Bermuda, Canada, Cayman Isl., Falkland Isl. (Malvinas),
>   Gibraltar, Israel, Japan, Korea (Rep.), Kuwait, New Zealand,
>   Oman, Qatar, Saudi Arabia, Switzerland, Turks and Caicos Isl.,
>   USA, United Arab Emirates or Virgin Isl. (British) for a
>   maximum stay of 90 days

The UK is an EEA state, so because you have a valid UK visa, you do **not** need a Georgian visa.

At the Georgian border, just present your passport open at the page with the visa

Comment: The UK is no longer an EEA member, having left the EEA in 2020. this answer is now (2023) inaccurate.

Comment: The answer as written is no longer correct but a rewrite of the rules still allows people with an UK visa into Georgia.